# Creating -24V @ 750 mA from a Variable DC lab supply

Tags: voltage, negative

I need -24V and 750 mA to run a certain part. What would be the best way to do so given that I have a power supply that gives me 24-28 volts and 2A of current. I need to do so because I need to create the -24V with respect to the ground of my positive power supply for my application. I have looked at various DC DC converters but none of them can provide that high a current. Also haven't been able to find any other power supplies which would work. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Many lab supplies (Instek, GW Precision) have three output connections: positive, negative and earth. If you disconnect earth from negative, you 'float' the output and can easily use it as a negative supply (put the positive to your ground, and the negative will provide your -DC).

Answer (score 2):

How about the [MC33063A](http://www.ti.com/product/mc33063a?qgpn=mc33063a) from Texas Instruments?  That should provide you -24V at 750mA quite happily.